# Firestore sends same image for diffrent documents in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore keeps sending the same image on the ListTile but different title and subtitle for different documents...Anybody who can solve this?

```
class HomeTabb extends StatelessWidget {
  
final CollectionReference _productsRef =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("products");

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _productsRef.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            return ListTile(
                leading: Image.network(
                  document.data()['picture'],
                  width: 80.0,
                  height: 80.0,
                ),
                title: Text(document.data()['name'] ?? "Product Name"),
                subtitle: Text(document.data()['price'] ?? "Product price")
                );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the content of your picture field from your data?

Comment: @JosephUtulu it's URL

Comment: Check if each data in your list has different URL

Comment: @JosephUtulu it's from firestore nd it's the same. it displays the latest uploaded image all over the leading

Comment: My point is, check the URL data from firestore and make sure all the URLs are different or unique, if they are the same URLs, then you will keep getting the same images loaded on each row of your ListView widget.

Comment: @JosephUtulu all URLs are different but the ListView loads the same image from one document...

Answer (score 1):

Try the builder pattern if it would work:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.size,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Image.network(
          snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['picture'],
          width: 80.0,
          height: 80.0,
       ),
       title: Text(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['name'] ?? "Product Name"),
       subtitle: Text(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['price'] ?? "Product price")
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: It worked when i delete the whole collection and re add the data's again in the collection

Comment: Wow... that's interesting

Comment: can i get your email address and we could contact...

Comment: joseph.utulu@gmail.com